# Kotlin didn't compile and the kapt broke down

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt

I try to run my tests and get the following error:
[image]

Here is full code:
https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/91b53af07b2b868e2b9b5968d7a24f0e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded to gradle version 7+ made all the necessary changes, it was also possible to roll back to earlier versions, which also solved my problem, but I decided to install the most current changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dagger or Hilt + Java 11, checkout this issue.
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2144